# Efficient mongodb querying when havin lots of html documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This question can seem simple, but I am not sure if I am using most efficient way for my problem.

I am using MongoDB version 3.2.4. I have a collection with only one field, `Html` (except id, ofc). There are altogether 8,821,851 documents. Every document holds a html file with around 20 pages of text (almost the same reports scraped from the net).

I want to do simple queries that search for documents that contain some text (for example where ID number is "5555888" or name "John"). I have tried some simple queries like:

```
db.collection.find(
    {"Html" :  /.*93335620125.*/}
)
db.collection.find(
    {"Html" :  /93335620125/}
)
db.zk1.findOne(
    {"Html" : {$regex : "John"}
)
```

but, unfortunately, they are all very very slow. Sometimes I don't even get any result in my IDEA (I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1).

Could somebody please recommend some more efficient way to query lots of large messy text documents with html tags?

**EDIT:**

I am giving example of one document (part of it):

```
"<a name=\"JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1\"></a>\n<table style=\"width: 595px; border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" bgcolor=\"white\">\n<tr>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 40px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 22px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 108px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 88px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 117px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 80px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 79px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 1px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"11\" style=\"width: 595px; height: 20px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 46px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"2\"><img src=\"/servlets/PublicReportServlet?_image_=img_0_0_9\" style=\"height: 46px\" alt=\"\"/></td>\n  <td colspan=\"6\" style=\"text-align: right;\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 18.0px; font-weight: bold;\">NESLUŽBENA KOPIJA</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 46px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">REPUBLIKA HRVATSKA</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"11\" style=\"width: 595px; height: 4px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">Općinski sud u Novom Zagrebu</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">ZEMLJIŠNOKNJIŽNI ODJEL NOVI ZAGREB</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"4\" style=\"border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #000000; \"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">Stanje na dan: 19.06.2016 23:05</span></td>\n  <td colspan=\"5\" style=\"border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #000000; text-align: right;\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px;\">Verificirani poduložak</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width:
```

Comment: Paste example document.

Comment: If the field contains text, best way is to use 'Text indexes' https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: @ CS_noob, I have already tried "Text indexes", but it always return an error. For example: `db.zk1.createIndex( {"Html": "MISLAV"} )` returnes an error: `bad index key pattern { Html: \"MISLAV\" }: Unknown index plugin 'MISLAV'"`

Comment: We should add text indexes like this. Try  db.coll.createIndex({html:"text"})

Comment: Ok. Done. Should I than use something like `db.coll.find({$text: {$search: "JOHN"}}` ?

Comment: Yes . Please use like that.

Comment: It's slow anyway. But  thanks...

Comment: @CS_noob  Text indexes are the correct solution, so you should write it up as an answer - then we can upvote and accept it.